# How to make one list of multiple headers

Tags: css, ruby, xml, parsing, nokogiri

I have this XML string:

```
xml = "<name>Married with Children</name>
<person age="20">Al Bundy</person>
<character age="20">Bud Bundy</character>
<character age="19">Marcy Darcy</character>
<person age="18">John Doe</person>"
```

I understand that if I use

```
xml.css("characters")
```

it would produce a list of character tagged headers, something like

```
[<character age="20">Bud Bundy</character>, <character age="19">Marcy Darcy</character>]
```

I just want to get rid of the name tag, so I want:

```
[<person age="20">Al Bundy</person>, 
 <character age="20">Bud Bundy</character>, 
 <character age="19">Marcy Darcy</character>, 
 <person age="18">John Doe</person>]
```

Is there a way to create a list of person OR character tagged?

Comment: `xml.css("characters")` will _not_ produce anything except `[]` given your XML as there are no `<characters>` tags. `css.('character')` would find two nodes. In addition, your XML is not syntactically correct because it's missing a root node. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". What did you try? We need to see evidence of your effort. Without that it looks like you want us to write the code for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has multiple issues but I'll try to sort things out so you understand what is going on, and how to write a better question in the future.

1. Your XML sample isn't formatted correctly:

   ```
   xml = "<name>Married with Children</name>
   <person age="20">Al Bundy</person>
   <character age="20">Bud Bundy</character>
   <character age="19">Marcy Darcy</character>
   <person age="18">John Doe</person>"

   -:3: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting end-of-input
   <person age="20">Al Bundy</person>
   ```

   You're getting this because you have outer double-quotes, and double-quotes wrapping the parameters. It's essential you make sure your sample data is usable when asking a question. It should look like:

   ```
   xml = '<name>Married with Children</name>
   <person age="20">Al Bundy</person>
   <character age="20">Bud Bundy</character>
   <character age="19">Marcy Darcy</character>
   <person age="18">John Doe</person>'
   ```

   or maybe:

   ```
   xml = <<EOT
   <name>Married with Children</name>
   <person age="20">Al Bundy</person>
   <character age="20">Bud Bundy</character>
   <character age="19">Marcy Darcy</character>
   <person age="18">John Doe</person>
   EOT
   ```

   At this point Ruby would let you begin testing your code.
2. Your sample XML doesn't have a root node. XML has a strict definition so, again, it's important to provide correct data:

   ```
   require 'nokogiri'

   xml = '<name>Married with Children</name>
   <person age="20">Al Bundy</person>
   <character age="20">Bud Bundy</character>
   <character age="19">Marcy Darcy</character>
   <person age="18">John Doe</person>'

   doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
   doc.to_xml # => "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<name>Married with Children</name>\n"
   ```

   If I use `doc.errors` Nokogiri will tell why it only has one node:

   ```
   doc.errors # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Extra content at the end of the document>]
   ```

   There are two ways to fix this, add a wrapping root node, or tell Nokogiri to treat the markup as a fragment of the document:

   ```
   doc = Nokogiri::XML('<root>' + xml + '</root>')
   doc.to_xml # => "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<root><name>Married with Children</name>\n<person age=\"20\">Al Bundy</person>\n<character age=\"20\">Bud Bundy</character>\n<character age=\"19\">Marcy Darcy</character>\n<person age=\"18\">John Doe</person></root>\n"
   ```

   or:

   ```
   doc = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(xml)
   doc.to_xml # => "<name>Married with Children</name>\n<person age=\"20\">Al Bundy</person>\n<character age=\"20\">Bud Bundy</character>\n<character age=\"19\">Marcy Darcy</character>\n<person age=\"18\">John Doe</person>"
   ```

   Notice the difference between the two DOMs after parsing. The first has the containing node, and the second has only the nodes in the sample XML.

   Now that the DOM is error-free you're safe to start parsing and gathering data. If you don't ensure your DOM is parsed correctly you could find that Nokogiri did fix-ups and altered the DOM to make it syntactically correct, resulting in a different structure than you expect. Dealing with that too often will make you go insane.
3. Use the right tag names when searching. This is pretty self-evident as you'll either get a result or will get nil or an empty NodeSet (`[]`):

   ```
   doc = Nokogiri::XML('<root>' + xml + '</root>')
   data = doc.css('characters') # => []
   data.class # => Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet
   data = doc.at_css('characters') # => nil
   ```

   whereas we want something like:

   ```
   data = doc.css('character') # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fc8c4c4d598 name="character" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fc8c4c4d4bc name="age" value="20">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fc8c4c4c544 "Bud Bundy">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fc8c4c49d44 name="character" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fc8c4c49ce0 name="age" value="19">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fc8c4c49830 "Marcy Darcy">]>]
   data = doc.at_css('character') # => #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fc8c4c4d598 name="character" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fc8c4c4d4bc name="age" value="20">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fc8c4c4c544 "Bud Bundy">]>
   ```

   or using the generic methods:

   ```
   data = doc.search('character') # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe8fe0771d8 name="character" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe8fe076ff8 name="age" value="20">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe8fe07633c "Bud Bundy">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe8fe07606c name="character" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe8fe073fd8 name="age" value="19">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe8fe073b50 "Marcy Darcy">]>]
   data = doc.at('character') # => #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe8fe0771d8 name="character" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe8fe076ff8 name="age" value="20">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe8fe07633c "Bud Bundy">]>
   ```

   Note that `at` and its `at_css` and `at_xpath` siblings is the equivalent of `search('for something').first`.

Moving on to one way to get at the data you want: You can use CSS's `,` operator to find multiple different nodes:

```
data = doc.search('character, person') # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7de018c7c name="person" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd7de018b8c name="age" value="20">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd7de015b80 "Al Bundy">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7de014fb4 name="character" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd7de014dd4 name="age" value="20">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd7de014550 "Bud Bundy">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7de014294 name="character" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd7de01421c name="age" value="19">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd7de011d00 "Marcy Darcy">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd7de011a94 name="person" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd7de011a30 name="age" value="18">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd7de0112d8 "John Doe">]>]
data.map(&:to_xml) # => ["<person age=\"20\">Al Bundy</person>", "<character age=\"20\">Bud Bundy</character>", "<character age=\"19\">Marcy Darcy</character>", "<person age=\"18\">John Doe</person>"]
```

That works, however you don't have total control of the order you'll get the resulting nodes, instead they'll be in the order they occur in the document. If you want control of that order you probably would want to do two separate searches then concatenate the NodeSets. How to do that is left for you to figure out.

To parse XML or HTML it's important to have a good understanding of CSS and/or XPath selectors. I suggest concentrating on CSS selectors because they're generally more readable. Also, Nokogiri implemented many of jQuery's CSS extensions as a convenience to use, which add power to the simplicity. XPath is much more powerful, but the price for that is a lot of visual noise. Still, you'll want to become familiar with it so you can pull out that tool from your tool chest when it's necessary.

You can use simplistic selectors then fold/spindle/mutilate the results in Nokogiri, but using the power of libXML requires giving it the information via the selector, so learning how to use them efficiently and correctly is really important. The difference in speed between making Nokogiri or libXML do the heavy lifting will quickly convince you of this.

Comment: A heroic answer, especially given the question's problems.

Comment: @WayneConrad, heh, yeah, where "heroic" means long-winded. :-)

Comment: Even as I voted to close the question, I up-voted this answer.  It deserves it.  I hope the OP edits the question into shape.